Search the latest saved PDF file in a various folders and copy the latest one to a specific location
I need a VBA Excel macro to find the latest saved PDF file in the folders and sub folder to get the latest (Creation date and time), then that needs to copy to a specific location.

The code below works only in the main folder, not in sub folders. Also, the file is being copyied from the source path, but not pasted into the destination path.
Sub copy_files_from_subfolders()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim fsofile As Object
    Dim fsofol As Object

    SourcePath = "C:\Users\OneDrive - Corporation\"
    destinationpath = "Z:\Project\Task 17"

    If Right(SourcePath, 1) <> "\" Then
    SourcePath = SourcePath & "\"
    End If

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(SourcePath)
    If fso.FolderExists(fld) Then
        For Each fsofol In fso.GetFolder(SourcePath).SubFolders
            For Each fsofile In fsofol.Files
                If Right(fsofile, 10) = "R-001-002.PDF" Then
                fsofile.Copy destinationpath
            End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
End Sub


I have checked the below code; Note that the first var fso is a public var so its placed outside the subs.
Dim fso As Object


Sub CopyFilesFromSubfolders()

Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim SourcePath As String
Dim DestinationPath As String

SourcePath = "C:\Data\Temp\pdf\test"
DestinationPath = "C:\Data\Temp\pdf"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

LatestFile = ""
LatestDate = #1/1/1900#
Call FindLatestPdf(fso.GetFolder(SourcePath), LatestFile, LatestDate)

If LatestFile <> "" Then
    fso.CopyFile LatestFile, DestinationPath & fso.GetFileName(LatestFile)
    MsgBox "Copied: " & fso.GetFileName(LatestFile), vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "No PDF files found.", vbExclamation
End If
End Sub


Sub FindLatestPdf(fld As Object, ByRef LatestFile As String, ByRef LatestDate As Date)
Dim fsofile As Object
Dim fsofol As Object
Dim CurrentFileDate As Date

   For Each fsofile In fld.Files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "pdf" Then
        CurrentFileDate = fsofile.DateLastModified ' or DateCreated
        If CurrentFileDate > LatestDate Then
            LatestDate = CurrentFileDate
            LatestFile = fsofile.Path
        End If
    End If
Next

' Recursively check subfolders
For Each fsofol In fld.SubFolders
    Call FindLatestPdf(fsofol, LatestFile, LatestDate)
Next
End Sub


You need to first go through the main folder and then loop through the subfolders. Also, keep in mind, there is a difference between datelastmodified and datecreated, so choose wisely.
Sub copy_files_from_subfolders()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim fsofile As Object
    Dim fsofol As Object
    Dim CurrentFileDate As Date
    Dim LatestDate As Date

    SourcePath = "C:\SourcePath\"
    DestinationPath = "C:\DestinationPath\"

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(SourcePath)
    If fso.FolderExists(fld) Then
        ' so first check the main path
        For Each fsofile In fld.Files
             If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "pdf" Then
                CurrentFileDate = fsofile.datelastmodified 'or datecreated
                If CurrentFileDate > LatestDate Then
                    LatestDate = CurrentFileDate
                    LatestFile = fsofile.Path
                End If
            End If
        Next
        
        'Now the subfolders
        For Each fsofol In fso.GetFolder(SourcePath).SubFolders
            For Each fsofile In fsofol.Files
                If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "pdf" Then
                    CurrentFileDate = fsofile.datelastmodified 'or datecreated
                    If CurrentFileDate > LatestDate Then
                        LatestDate = CurrentFileDate
                        LatestFile = fsofile.Path
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
    
    If LatestFile <> "" Then
        fso.CopyFile LatestFile, DestinationPath & fso.GetFileName(LatestFile)
    Else
        MsgBox "No PDF files.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub


Thanks for the response. I tired with your code but let me know where again am missing ?
Following changes I did in the code
SourcePath = "C:\Users\OneDrive - Corporation"
DestinationPath = "Z:\Project\Task 17"
If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "R-001-002.pdf"  (both main and subfolder)
not resolved

Try using LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "r-001-002.pdf" as LCase will never return an upper case "R"

Tired doesn't work for me.

Did you try to debug it? Place a breakpoint at both the "For Each fsofile In fld.Files" statements to check if it finds any files?

If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "r-001-002.pdf" Then
((fsofile) -  "C:\Users\OneDrive - Corporation\r-001-002.pdf" ))
After this line its not finding the PDF file from the location and skip the rest of the following lines. and End sub
Breakpoint at "For Each fsofile In fld.Files" are shows nothing

Note that GetExcentionName returns the extention (do PDF) just .name returns the filename

Sorry.! Am new to VBA can you explain what you mean ?

LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) gets the extention, so '.pdf' instead of the complete filname. So you should use LCase(fso.Name(fsofile))

If I use  If LCase(fso.Name(fsofile)) = "r-001-002" Then Getting run time error 438

My Bad, it is fso.getbaseName(fsofile) for the filename without extension. fso.filename(fsofile) is the filename with extension

Thanks.!!!! Now the code is rocking as I want. But can we make sub-folder to sub-folder to go deep ? bcz this only getting into one subfolder

Thanks for the code, But am getting following message even If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "r-001-002.pdf" and If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "r-001-002" in both case i got message "No PDF found"

change the getextensionname to what you had last time

fso.getbaseName(fsofile) for the filename without extension works well, But When I try with fso.filename(fsofile)  is the filename with extension not working. Because some time I use to have ".STEP" or ".DWG" format, can we use with extension to get all these format ?

So basically you can have:

So you can have:
Name = complete filename without the path
GetBaseName= filename without extension
GetExtensionName = the file’s extension (eg “.PDF”)
Path = full file path

Sorry to bother you again, Can you help me to figure out how to write a code according to the different formats ? (PDF, .STEP
, ".DWG")

Change 'If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "pdf" Then' into: 'If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "pdf" or If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "step or If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "dwg Then that will check all three extensions and will place the latest one in the other folder

as suggest modified the your code, I have posted a full code kindly check If I did something wrong ? all three files should copy to the location. But actually not working

What is the Latestfile = "" does ? I tired two methods as you mentioned nothing copied for me

Dim fso As Object

Sub CopyFilesFromSubfolders()

Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim SourcePath As String
Dim DestinationPath As String

SourcePath = "D:\TTC"
DestinationPath = "D:\Design\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

LatestFile = ""

Call FindLatestPdf(fso.GetFolder(SourcePath), LatestFile, LatestDate)

If LatestFile <> "" Then
    fso.copyFile LatestFile, DestinationPath & fso.GetExtensionName(LatestFile)
    MsgBox "Copied: " & fso.GetFileName(LatestFile), vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "No PDF files found.", vbExclamation
End If

End Sub

Sub FindLatestPdf(fld As Object, ByRef LatestFile As String, ByRef LatestDate As Date)
Dim fsofile As Object
Dim fsofol As Object
Dim CurrentFileDate As Date

   For Each fsofile In fld.Files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "r-001-002.pdf" Or _
       UCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "r-001-002.STEP" Or _
       LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsofile)) = "r-001-002.dwg" Then
    
        CurrentFileDate = fsofile.DateLastModified ' or DateCreated
            If CurrentFileDate > LatestDate Then
                LatestDate = CurrentFileDate
                LatestFile = fsofile.Path
            End If
        End If
    Next

' Recursively check subfolders
For Each fsofol In fld.SubFolders
    Call FindLatestPdf(fsofol, LatestFile, LatestDate)
Next

End Sub


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

first of all you use getExtensioName which only gets the extension (not the filename plus extension),
so you should use "name" instead. If you need all three there are 2 options, or you run Call the FindLatestPdf sub three times (with an extra parameter filetype)
or you change "FindLatestPdf" to support all three extensions. Below an example for the first option.
    Dim fso As Object

Sub CopyFilesFromSubfolders()
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim SourcePath As String
Dim DestinationPath As String
    
    SourcePath = "D:\TTC"
    DestinationPath = "D:\Design\"
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    LatestFile = ""
    
    Call FindLatestPdf(fso.GetFolder(SourcePath), LatestFile, LatestDate, "PDF")
    Call FindLatestPdf(fso.GetFolder(SourcePath), LatestFile, LatestDate, "DWG")
    Call FindLatestPdf(fso.GetFolder(SourcePath), LatestFile, LatestDate, "STEP")

End Sub

Sub FindLatestPdf(fld As Object, ByRef LatestFile As String, ByRef LatestDate As Date, ByRef Filetype As String)
Dim fsofile As Object
Dim fsofol As Object
Dim CurrentFileDate As Date

   For Each fsofile In fld.Files
    If LCase(fso.Name(fsofile)) = Filetype Then
        CurrentFileDate = fsofile.DateLastModified ' or DateCreated
            If CurrentFileDate > LatestDate Then
                LatestDate = CurrentFileDate
                LatestFile = fsofile.Path
            End If
        End If
    Next


    For Each fsofol In fld.SubFolders
        Call FindLatestPdf(fsofol, LatestFile, LatestDate)
    Next
    
    If LatestFile <> "" Then
        fso.copyFile LatestFile, DestinationPath & fso.GetExtensionName(LatestFile)
        MsgBox "Copied: " & fso.GetFileName(LatestFile), vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No  files found.", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub

